# How to reinitialize git in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: git, netbeans

I searched through a few posts and couldn't find a suitable answer, so I thought I'd go ahead and ask here.

I'm trying to create a Github repository for my project, but when I intialized it in Netbeans I accidentally connected to someone *else's* repo, because I'm using some of their code in my own project. Now I can't seem to get rid of the settings and start over. How do I do that, and then upload my project to Github?

Answer (score 3):

Close NB, manually remove the `.git` folder and start again.

Comment: I tried that, but it just gave me an error because the folder was missing.

Comment: Take care of closing Netbeans while deleting the folder. As long as I can see, NB does not keep information about the use of Git in the project. In extreme cases you can delete the `.netbeans/7.1/var/cache` folder. I've tried doing what I told you and it worked fine. What error do you get?

Comment: This worked for me. I went straight to the deleting the cache option because I've done that tons of times when experiencing problems with Netbeans and it always seems to fix my problems :) It just takes a bit of time. Thanks for the tip!